# Pass value to non-sequential activity

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development and was unable to find how to pass values to an activity that is not the next screen that the user will see. If I have activities in this order: 1>2>3 connected by buttons, how do I pass a value from 1 to 3? I'm only familiar with using intents on button clicks, which would require me to pass the value to screen 2 and then to screen 3.

Thanks

Comment: "which would require me to pass the value to screen 2 and then to screen 3" and what's wrong with that?

Comment: It just seems like unnecessary code if a better way exists.

Comment: Using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: There are many ways to do this, no way is just "better" than the other, it all depends on your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

1) From `Activity1` you pass data though `Intent`. In `Activity2` you retrieve data and pass it within new `Intent` to `Acitivity3`.

2) Save data in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in `Activity1` and retrieve them in `Activity3`.

3) Save data in [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) database which is default for Android. This is a good option if you need to save/query data not once, but many times.

4) Save in [Google Cloud](https://developer.android.com/google/gcs/index.html) or use other services.

You can see here a full bunch of [store options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) in Android. Without performing those actions, storing/retrieving data though the `Intent` is the only one way.

Note: Make a static variables is such a bad practice, unless it is just constant values or other utilities.

Answer (score 0):

If the chain pass becomes too complicated then you should persist it. My suggestion is using Preferences to save the value. Later you do an existence check in the retrieving Activity, load it, and if needed clear it. This is the method commonly used when storing app Settings values.

If your values become more complicated in structure and more numerous then you'd need to consider database.